# What does "Previous definition of x was here" in Ruby mean?

Tags: ruby

In my Sinatra/activerecord app, rake test gives me this odd series of warnings:

```
/Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/slice.rb:21: warning: method redefined; discarding old slice
/Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/arel-8.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/informix.rb:21: warning: assigned but unused variable - froms
/Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bunny-2.9.2/lib/bunny/cruby/ssl_socket.rb:110: warning: assigned but unused variable - le
/Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bunny-2.9.2/lib/bunny/session.rb:259: warning: method redefined; discarding old port
/Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bunny-2.9.2/lib/bunny/queue.rb:384: warning: method redefined; discarding old add_default_options
/Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bunny-2.9.2/lib/bunny/queue.rb:379: warning: previous definition of add_default_options was here
/Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bunny-2.9.2/lib/bunny/channel.rb:1580: warning: method redefined; discarding old to_s
/Users/pitosalas/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bunny-2.9.2/lib/bunny/channel.rb:257: warning: previous definition of to_s was here
```

I am mainly interested in the messages like: `warning: previous definition of to_s was here`

What are they telling me? I can't find any clear reference to that message on line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a two part warning.

> bunny-2.9.2/lib/bunny/channel.rb:1580: warning: method redefined; discarding old to_s
>
> bunny-2.9.2/lib/bunny/channel.rb:257: warning: previous definition of to_s was here

It's telling you `to_s` was defined for that class at `channel.rb:257`, then another definition of `to_s` for the same class was found at `channel.rb:1580`. It's warning you about the ambiguity and how it resolved it by using the one at `channel.rb:1580`.

Comment: Are you saying this is a standard Ruby warning... One that the ruby itself is generating as it parses the file? Has ruby always detected that error?

Comment: @pitosalas Yes, it's a standard warning in Ruby and many languages. Ruby only issues it if you turn warnings on. This is usually done with `ruby -w`, though there's probably other ways.

Comment: Thanks. Ive been using ruby for years and don't remember ever seeing it. I thought it was coming out of bunny :)

Comment: @pitosalas Turning on warnings can be quite a shock. :) It's good to develop with them on. They can be annoying, but it's worth it to catch mistakes that you'd otherwise might be pulling your hair out trying to debug. Like "*why isn't my `to_s` method running?!*" (because you have a 2nd one shadowing it)